# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image_field'

Tags: python, django

I've profiles for clinics and would like to add images for each of them. I'm trying to use [django-imaging](https://github.com/pielgrzym/django-imaging) and getting this error. I've followed the documentation and did the following:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'm1',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'imaging',
```

models.py

```
from imaging.fields import ImagingField

class Clinic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique = True)
    photos = models.ImagingField()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^imaging/', include('imaging.urls')),
```

I then tried doing `syncdb`and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/harisaghadi/code/meddy Production App/meddy1/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    from imaging.fields import ImagingField
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_imaging-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/imaging/fields.py", line 6, in <module>
    from imaging.models import Image
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_imaging-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/imaging/models.py", line 22, in <module>
    class Image(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_imaging-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/imaging/models.py", line 31, in Image
    options={'quality':90}
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image_field'
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Added the full traceback

Comment: `photos = models.ImagingField()` should be `photos = ImagingField()`, given your import line.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Django Imaging; see [issue #11 in their tracker](https://github.com/pielgrzym/django-imaging/issues/11):

> django-imagekit has been updated and the `image_field` kwarg has been renamed to `source`, its a bug in django-imaging and needs to be fixed.

That rename [took place quite some time ago](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/commit/d253fe281ad55620e116f2cce9c7262e613de7a7), in December 2012.

The work-around would be to downgrade Django-Imagekit to version 2.0.2, the last release with the field still named `image_field`. However, a project that hasn't been maintained to fix a field rename from 2 and a half years ago is perhaps not production worthy. Issue #11 was filed over a year ago and hasn't been fixed in all that time.

Answer (score -1):

In your models.py, try
`photos = ImagingField()`
instead of
`photos = models.ImagingField()`

Please read documentation https://github.com/pielgrzym/django-imaging

> Add ImagingField to desired model from imaging.fields import
>   ImagingField
>
> class Somemodel(models.Model):
>       photos = ImagingField()

Comment: From the traceback *and* from the code the OP posted: `from imaging.fields import ImagingField`. The `models.` prefix is probably an error. In any case, there is no `models.ImagingField` in the Django-Imaging project.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but OP has error in models.py, correcting which could solve the problem. I have also given the source of documentation.

Comment: Look closely at the traceback; it is the `from imaging.fields import ImagingField` import that triggers the issue. Then look at my answer; this is a known bug with the project.